# Can I transfer books to my Kindle Cloud reader?

Tags: kindle, kindle-cloud-reader

I have several books loaded directly on my Kindle.  I did not purchase them through Amazon.  Is there a way to transfer them to my cloud reader?

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, no.

If you try long-pressing on any books that you have on your device, it will allow you to add it to a collection, but this warning pops up, saying this will not sync the item to cloud.

[image: Content not synced]

Comment: Perhaps true at the time, now there's a work-around.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

Convert to `.mobi` [with an online converter](https://www.epubconverter.com/epub-to-mobi-converter/) and [attach it as an e-mail to yourself](https://www.amazon.com/gp/sendtokindle/email) (`foo@kindle.com`).  It will show in `kindle.com/myk` under "docs" (not "books") and be synced to your device.